# Get activity instance

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Excuse me for simple question,I'm completely beginner java and android developer. How I can get the instance of Activity in setCameraDisplayOrientation when surfaceChanged is called?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    public final int cameraId = 0;
    public Activity activity = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    activity = this; 

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
    }

    public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
                        int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {

    }

    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    ...
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        ...
        setCameraDisplayOrientation(activity, cameraId, mCamera);
        ....
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you need its instance. Its overridden method, it will have some activity context. But still if you want, try using `MyActivity.this`

Comment: I use `this` but program crash when surfaceChanged called. Ok. I'll check again why program crash. I need this instance to call its method in context: `activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
     .getRotation()`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is a way to avoid memory leaks using static variable: make static weak reference to Activity instance that will be set in onCreate(Bundle) method.

1. Write in your secondary class something like below:

   ```
   public Class SecondClass {
       private static WeakReference<Activity> mActivityRef;
       public static void updateActivity(Activity activity) {
           mActivityRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
       }
   ```
2. Then in onCreate(Bundle) method of your Activity class:

   ```
   @Override
   onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       SecondClass.updateActivity(this);
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Use activity instance this way:

   ```
   mActivityRef.get()
   ```

Comment: This is the way to go if you want store Activity instance on static variables &  avoid memory leaks

Comment: This is totally wrong, Android activities are recreated under memory pressure, in that case, you are holding a wrong reference of destroyed activity !!

Comment: I meant that it could be used untill memory will pressured and could be updated every time when app returnd to foreground.

Comment: Miha_x64, singleton just an app structure model which could be applied to any object as an app structure part. So 1 - This code working fine which could be tested. 2 - Do not say about things you not understand.

Comment: I can confirm this solves memory leak issues, as LeakCanary reported a memory leak before this implementation, and it went away after.

Answer (score 8):

```
Activity a = (Activity) getContext();
```

As long as you pass the current activity as a context in the constructor, as you are already doing.

Answer (score 4):

I just set a variable in my main activity like so... `public static Activity activity = this;` then I can reference it from anywhere using: `MainActivity.activity`.

You can also set it in the onCreate() method, just set up the variable at the top of your main activity class like this `public static Activity activity;` then in the onCreate() method just add `activity = this;` anywhere.

This will work for any class that extends Activity, for example `public class MainActivity extends Activity` however you can call the variable from any class even if they don't extend Activity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Memory leak, as stated below

Comment: This can definitely cause memory leaks by keeping reference to a static context (the activity).

Comment: Don't you get the compile error `Cannot use this in a static context`?

Comment: Please don't spread this kind of technique as it produces bad coding style, hard to maintain code base, and various problems such as memory leaks.
Hope people would allot a time to read Android best practices and design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Method `this.getParent()` works.