# Communication between activity and separate class

Tags: android, interface, listener, handler

I have an Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
// TODO: send event to other class
    }
}
```

and a separate class:

```
    public class MyClass{
        MyClass(Context context){
          // I have the context of activity
        }

// This needs to be called by MyActivity in all other instantiates
        void onActivityDestroy(){

        }
    }
```

MyClass is instantiated in other places and I want onActivityDestroy to be called in those instantiates. The place where MyClass is instantiated is not accessible.

I am looking for a solution that uses interfaces, listener, messages... but not static fields.

Comment: Why don't you call  MyClass cs = new MyClass(); 
cs.onActivityDestry(); in your activty onDestroy() method.

Comment: The MyClass is instantiated in other place and I need to run onActivityDestroy there. Not in the instantiates created by me.

Comment: I don't think that's what the desired behavior is, they want to call the onDestroy method of MyActivity, not MyClass.

Comment: You might want to ask how to get the instance of MyActivity from within the constructor of MyClass. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723106/get-activity-instance

Comment: That is exactly what I did until now but I want to avoid using "static" and especially avoid static Context.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using static?

Comment: I recently [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948709/android-custom-listener-for-an-event/39948968#39948968) a question on using a custom listener to get notified on an `Activity`'s event. Take a look, might be helpful.

Comment: @Glen Pierce - My app is getting bigger and using static everywere makes it very hard to keep working on it

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the list of `MyClass` instances at application level then access that list in `OnDestroy` method of activity. And execute `onActivityDestroy()` version of each instance.

You should maintain list of instances in your Application class, whenever `MyClass` instance is created, you push that instance to the list maintained at `Application` Class

```
// this is to push the MyClass instance.
Context.getApplication().getMyClassInstanceList().add(new MyClass());

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  @Override 
  protected void onDestroy() { 
    List<Myclass> myClassObjects = Context.getApplication.getMyClassInstaceList();

    for(Myclass myclass : myClassObjects)
     {
          myclass.onActivityDestroy();
     }
   }
 }
```