# How to getRotation(); in non-activity class

Tags: android, device, android-orientation, screen-rotation

I have four.java class files:

1. `FragmentActivity` that contains a View Pager.
2. `BlankFragment`, testing purpose only.
3. `CameraFragment`.
4. `CameraPreview`.
   My question is, how do I get display rotation from my `FragmentActivity` into `CameraPreview` class?

Example: This doesn’t work....

```
int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by it does not work?

Comment: I am attempting to pass `Context` from my `FragmentActivity`that contains the `ViewPager`, to the `CameraPreview` class, in order to obtain device orientation. I found the answer here,
 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723106/get-activity-instance).