# Getting instance of MainActivity

Tags: android

Hi I am kind of new to android, still learning. And my problem is that, for example I have a method which was created in the MainActivity and I need to call it from another class.

Is it a good practice to get the instance of the MainActivity so that I may be able to call the method in the MainActivity from another class?

This is an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private static MainActivity inst;

public static MainActivity instances()
{
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void showToast (String text){
    Toast.makeText(inst, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Then this is the other class:

```
public class broadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  MainActivity instance = new MainActivity();

 instance.showToast(AnyText);
    }
}
```

I saw this type of coding while looking at tutorials and wondered if it's a good practice or maybe there might be a better way? Since I get the warning of **Do not place Android Context Classes in static classes**

Thanks in advance for any insight or help! :D

Comment: I think you can directly create instance wherever you want using `MainActivity instance = new MainActivity();` Don't need to return instance of any class using any method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get activity instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723106/get-activity-instance)

Answer (score 0):

I guess You want to make A singleton  of Activity Class

but as Mention in All **Pattern Design**

**using Singleton**

If and Only If its only way to Make A Global Variable

**Singleton** is based on Lazing Initialing and Load On Memory

so I guess If you cant to Interact With Activiy You can Use

**BroadCast** Or **Intents**

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good practice to get the instance of the MainActivity so that
>   I may be able to call the method in the MainActivity from another
>   class?

You totally can do this but you don't need to make it static and use a constructor. Just create a new instance like follows and you'll access the public methods

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity.showToast(text);
```

About the warning

It suggests avoiding having context fields defined as static. The warning itself explains why: It's a memory leak. If you make it static it will be accessible anywhere in your app and some methods can hold the reference to this context for a really long time and it won't be garbage collected. It will lead to a outofmemory exception and the app could crash. But here you're trying to invoke `showToast()` from broadcastreceiver so you can just  get rid of static references. And it you need them in the future you safe ways to inject context

Answer (score 0):

You can call method from another class like this:

```
MainActivity instance = new MainActivity();
String data = instance.data();
```

and create data method in that class:

```
public String data() {
    return mangaId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create instances of an `Activity` using the `new` operator.

You have to use an `Intent` to let an Activity to be created.

So you cannot get a reference to an instance of your activity.

The only methods you can use of your activity class are static ones.